# If user "cancels" prompt box then

Tags: javascript

I have tried adding a Do/While loop, then I tried a If statement but I can't seem to get this to work.

I am trying to determine if the user hasn't made three guesses, and hits cancel on the userGuess prompt .. it would then return a alert("You are a chicken");

```
//declare variables
var sportsArray = new Array("Football", "Basketball", "Rollerblading", "Hiking", "Biking", "Swimming");
var name = "";
var score = 0;
var loops = 0;


// prompts for user name, checks for input.
do {
    name = prompt("Enter your first name", "");
}
while (name == "");


for (loops = 1;loops <=3; loops++) {

    var sGuess = prompt("Enter a sport guess", "");
    // uses substrings to ultimately capitalize the 1st letter, and make everything after it lowerCase.
    var sFirstPart = sGuess.substr(0, 1);
    var sFirstCap = sFirstPart.toUpperCase();
    var sSecondPart = sGuess.substring(1, sGuess.length);
    var sSecondLow = sSecondPart.toLowerCase();
    // concats the two parts into one string
    var usableGuess = sFirstCap + sSecondLow;

    // if user hits cancel on the sGuess prompt
    if (sGuess == "") { 
        alert("You are a chicken");
    }

    // checks if usableGuess is contained in the arry or not.
    if (sportsArray.indexOf(usableGuess) === -1) { 
            document.write("Sorry! Try again.<br />");
            score = score -5;
        } 

        else { 
            document.write("You are good, try again.<br />"); 
            score = score + 5;
            }
    }
    //depending on the user score, prompts one of three messages.
    if (score < 0) { 
        document.write(name + ", you do not demonstrate ESP tendencies at this time.<br />");
        } else if (score < 15) { 
            document.write(name + ", you are not bad.<br />");
            } else { 
                document.write("<br/>" + name + ", you are a mind reader!<br />");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the result to see if there was a value supplied:

```
 name = prompt("Enter your first name", "");

 // If no name value was received:
 if(!name){
      alert("Chicken!");
 }
```

Comment: when i apply this one it appears to work properly, when the input prompt is left empty and cancel is hit.

Comment: That's right. Because if the user leaves the prompt empty, `null` is returned (which is a 'falsy' value - it converts to false when needed to be treated as a Boolean) and when the user types nothing and hits OK, an empty string is returned (also falsy). So, both actions mean the user didn't type anything.

Comment: thank you very much Scott, new to Javascript. I'm still trying to grasp what types of loops to use in different circumstances and what to do when a "null" or empty string is returned.  thanks much.

Comment: Your welcome @NateE. Don't forget to up vote!  Good luck!

Comment: Down Vote? Why? Correct explanation and OP commented that he was happy.

Answer (score 2):

The prompt return s a `null` value where clicked on cancel, so your `substring()` method fails with an error(`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null`).

You need to check it as soon as the prompt is called, then continue like

```
  var sGuess = prompt("Enter a sport guess", "");
  if (sGuess == "") {
    alert("You are a chicken");
    continue;
  }
```

Comment: `continue;` is not needed, since there's no code after it.

Comment: this one doesn't setoff an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Update `sGuess` checking from:

```
if (sGuess == "") { 
        alert("You are a chicken");
}
```

to next one:

```
if (sGuess == null) { 
        alert("You are a chicken");
}
```

If user click cancel sGuess would be equal to  `null`, to verify third user tries was ended with cancel pressing add checking for `loops` counter value `(sGuess == null && loops == 3)`.

Comment: this one doesn't trigger the alert.

Answer (score 0):

"prompt" is returning null if the user hits cancel. In this case all your substr and subsequent code will fail.

```
    var sGuess = prompt("Enter a sport guess", "");
    if(sGuess !== null) {
        // uses substrings to ultimately capitalize the 1st letter, and make everything after it lowerCase.
        var sFirstPart = sGuess.substr(0, 1);
        var sFirstCap = sFirstPart.toUpperCase();
        var sSecondPart = sGuess.substring(1, sGuess.length);
        var sSecondLow = sSecondPart.toLowerCase();
        // concats the two parts into one string
        var usableGuess = sFirstCap + sSecondLow;

    } else {
        // if user hits cancel on the sGuess prompt
        alert("You are a chicken");
    }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following and it does the job, in this particular case.

```
    // if user hits cancel on the sGuess prompt
    if (!sGuess && loops < 4) { 
        alert("You are a chicken");
    }
```